# Ram not consistent, system stability issue additional

Tags: boot, ram

Okay so got a few things going on, no idea if they are linked or not.
First a little info on my setup:

Desktop unit, running Ubuntu 14.04 as only OS, with encryption option. 32GB ram installed, 32gb swap set up and registering. 6 core amd processor on a MSI board, gallium graphics unit. Internal HDDs are a 1TB main and a 500gb storage as secondary that is nearly full, 2 external drives for additional storage that are also nearly full, both externals are seagates 1 is a 3TB used mainly for movies and music.

So the system was running alright for a while, couple hiccups with hardware compatibility for unessential crap like webcam but no big deal. now today it starts showing 1 less ram stick in sysytem monitor and details (what should be 32 showing as 26, what should be 26 showing as 16) but when i punch "sudo lshw -class memory" into terminal it reads all 4 8gb sticks as being there no problem, bios reads them fine, memtest registers same amount as system monitor and system details.

I pulled the sticks and was in process of testing each ram stick when i ran into a bigger problem, the OS stopped booting after one of the reboots. It would go from my bios splash screen to the selection screen that allows me to run memtest or load ubuntu or select a different ubuntu to load instead of going to my encryption passcode prompt screen. no matter what ubuntu option i picked i was unable to get it to boot, it would got the Ubuntu 14.04 screen with the progress dots and then from there dump me to this..busybox v1.21.1 with prompt "initramfs" and not let me go any further. Removed all but main drive and loaded the install disc and ran a check on disc, no errors reported, booted to the try option and made sure gparted could see the disc, no problems there, even was able to mount and view files to verify they were there. tried to boot without disc, tried got tossed back to that busybox thing, tried to mount disc got told etc/fstab was nonexistant even though it had shown on drive.

I took a break, went and ate, came back and booted with all the ram in and just the main drive, after a few failures it let me boot back up. I have a nasty suspicion this problem is just a single reboot away from happening again and would love some input on what could be going wrong and options on fixing it that hopefully won't make me lose all my data. Unfortunately backing the data up on another drive is not an option at this time.

Current status is machine is booted with only main drive and still reading 1 less stick of ram than is present when i look in system monitor and system details. Here is the readout of lshw in case i missed something that might point to a solution for at least 1 of the things going on:

```
sythja@CMOMEGA:~$ sudo lshw -class memory
[sudo] password for sythja: 
  *-firmware              
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: V22.5
       date: 10/12/2012
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 8128KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
   description: L1 cache
   physical id: 5
   slot: L1-Cache
   size: 288KiB
   capacity: 288KiB
   clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
   capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
  *-cache:1
   description: L2 cache
   physical id: 6
   slot: L2-Cache
   size: 6MiB
   capacity: 6MiB
   clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
   capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
  *-cache:2
   description: L3 cache
   physical id: 7
   slot: L3-Cache
   size: 8MiB
   capacity: 8MiB
   clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
   capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
  *-memory
   description: System Memory
   physical id: 27
   slot: System board or motherboard
   size: 32GiB
     *-bank:0
      description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
      product: Array1_PartNumber0
      vendor: A1_Manufacturer0
      physical id: 0
      serial: A1_SerNum0
      slot: A1_DIMM0
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
     *-bank:1
      description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
      product: Array1_PartNumber1
      vendor: A1_Manufacturer1
      physical id: 1
      serial: A1_SerNum1
      slot: A1_DIMM1
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
     *-bank:2
      description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
      product: Array1_PartNumber2
      vendor: A1_Manufacturer2
      physical id: 2
      serial: A1_SerNum2
      slot: A1_DIMM2
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
     *-bank:3
      description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
      product: Array1_PartNumber3
      vendor: A1_Manufacturer3
      physical id: 3
      serial: A1_SerNum3
      slot: A1_DIMM3
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
```

Comment: Have you checked the RAM thoroughly with `memtest`? Like, letting it run for several hours, overnight? Also, if you manage to boot, can you include the output of the command `free`? This will show what amount of RAM Linux sees.